# Count if function in nested sql query

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have following query in sql server 2005 with a table

```
select t1.id, CONVERT(VARCHAR,t1.dt,103) date_1, CONVERT(VARCHAR,t2.dt,103) date_2, t1.hotel,
    t1.price price_1, t2.price price_2, t2.price - t1.price difference, ((t2.price - t1.price)/t1.price)*100 as Diff_percentage
from test t1
inner join
(
    select *
    from test
) t2
    on t1.hotel = t2.hotel
    and t1.dt < t2.dt and t2.dt=(SELECT MAX(dt) from TEST) and t1.dt=(SELECT MAX(dt-1) from TEST)
```

I want to use count if function within this query. Based on difference column. So that i can count "How many increased, How many decreased, How many same, How many unavailable"

1. COUNT IF Difference>0  //How many increased
2. COUNT IF Difference<0  //How many decreased
3. COUNT IF Difference=0  //How many same
4. COUNT IF Difference=""  //How many unavailable --Difference is blank.

DEMO : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6f37/29

Comment: FYI, `COUNT IF X` is equivalent to a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE X`

Comment: How to optimize this code in with my query. As i am getting error because column name difference is alias column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I wanted your existing query result I would rewrite the query as:

```
select t1.id, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR,t1.dt,103) date_1, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR,t2.dt,103) date_2, 
       t1.hotel,
       t1.price price_1, 
       t2.price price_2, 
       t2.price - t1.price difference, 
       ((t2.price - t1.price)/t1.price)*100 as Diff_percentage
  from test t1
  join (select max(dt) maxDt from test) d
    on t1.dt = d.maxDt-1
  join test t2
    on t2.hotel = t1.hotel
   and t2.dt = d.maxDt
```

To extend your original query to include hotels with missing rows:

```
select t1.id, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR,t1.dt,103) date_1, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR,t2.dt,103) date_2, 
       h.hotel,
       t1.price price_1, 
       t2.price price_2, 
       t2.price - t1.price difference, 
       ((t2.price - t1.price)/t1.price)*100 as Diff_percentage
  from (select distinct hotel from test) h
  cross join (select max(dt) maxDt from test) d
  left join test t1
    on t1.hotel = h.hotel
   and t1.dt = d.maxDt-1
  left join test t2
    on t2.hotel = h.hotel
   and t2.dt = d.maxDt
```

The above query would be much more efficient with a normalized HOTEL table (1 row per hotel) to replace the SELECT DISTINCT subquery.

To get your requested result, I would use:

```
select count(case when (t2.price-t1.price) < 0 then 1 end) decrease_count,
       count(case when (t2.price-t1.price) > 0 then 1 end) increase_count,
       count(case when (t2.price-t1.price) = 0 then 1 end) same_count,
       count(distinct t1.hotel) - count(case when (t2.price-t1.price) is not null then 1 end) unavailable_count
  from test t1
  left join (select max(dt) maxDt from test) d
    on t1.dt = d.maxDt-1
  left join test t2
    on t2.hotel = t1.hotel
   and t2.dt = d.maxDt
```

Again the above would be more efficient with a normalized HOTEL table. I would restructure the query more like the previous one: select from HOTEL cross joined to the MAX date query, then outer join to the TEST table twice for the data for the 2 dates. The unavailable count could then be measured more directly, counting the number of rows where the difference computation is NULL.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4defa/2) for all the queries, along with some extended test data.

Comment: What's your purpose with the left joins? I might be missing something but I don't think you'd want rows back without the matches.

Comment: @shawnt00 - To get a count for hotels that are missing data for one or both dates. See the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I did, and briefly tested it. I guess if the answer is accepted it's probably fine, but I don't see where OP requested such behavior.

Comment: EDIT - Showed how to extend the 1st query to include hotels with missing rows.

Comment: @shawnt00 - The question definitely could be improved to make the requirements more clear. I was puzzled by the request for an "unavailable" count, yet the price in all test data was populated. Then I noticed that hotel DE did not have a row for the max date, and I surmised that "unavailable" was referring to the missing rows.

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses your query and then just summarizes the results:

```
with t as (
    select t1.id, CONVERT(VARCHAR,t1.dt,103) as date_1,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR,t2.dt,103) as date_2,
           t1.hotel,
           t1.price as price_1, t2.price as price_2,
           t2.price - t1.price as difference,
           ((t2.price - t1.price)/t1.price)*100 as Diff_percentage
    from test t1 join
         test t2
    on t1.hotel = t2.hotel and
       t1.dt < t2.dt and
       t2.dt=(SELECT MAX(dt) from TEST) and
       t1.dt=(SELECT MAX(dt-1) from TEST)
)
select sum(case when diff_percentage > 0.0 then 1 else 0 end) as numIncrease,
       sum(case when diff_percentage < 0.0 then 1 else 0 end) as numDecrease,
       sum(case when diff_percentage = 0.0 then 1 else 0 end) as numSame,
       sum(case when diff_percentage is NULL then 1 else 0 end) as numBlank
from t
```

I'm not sure what "dt - 1" means.  With date/datetime values in SQL Server, one usually uses "dateadd(day, -1, )" to subtract a date.  In any case, there may be other ways to calculate what you want, but this answers your specific question.

Comment: That strategy won't work properly for the "blank" count because there is no outer join. The hotels with one or both dates missing will not be counted. I too was surprised to see "dt-1" with SQL Server, though it seems to work the same as Oracle.

Comment: @dbenham . . . You are assuming that the price field itself is never NULL.  The question seemed to suggest that blanks/NULLs were returned by the original query.

Comment: No, I'm not assuming the price is never NULL. But I was wondering how to interpret the "blank" difference - the question was not very clear. Then I noticed hotel DE did not have an entry for the max date. I figured that hotel was put in the example for a reason. My answer gives a "blank" count for both null values and missing rows. Yours gives a "blank" count only for null values - a perfectly reasonable answer, but I'm guessing not what the OP wanted.

Comment: @dbenham . . . I am guessing that is exactly what s/he wanted, since the question specifically says "I want to use count if function within this query. Based on difference column."